# Form fields missing in Django, just button visable

Tags: django, forms

New to Django and having problem seeing form fields displayed. What I see is just the submit button. If pressed, the form is finally presented, but with the format for a form that had bad data (typical 'this field is required' error for each box, red box, etc).
The form works fine after entering data and again pressing submit (stores entries in my db). I have a number of forms on the same page that have the same behavior.

Example of one form:

```
#model
class dbPara(models.Model):  #parameters
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    turns = models.FloatField(default=27)
    units = models.FloatField(default=5)
    rise = models.FloatField(default=2.9)
    rescutL = models.FloatField(default=0.0833333333)
    rescutH = models.FloatField(default=0.333333333)
    LorR = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='R')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.timestamp, self.username, self.turns, self.units, self.rise, self.rescutL, self.rescutH, self.LorR

#form
class ParaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = dbPara
        widgets = {'username': forms.HiddenInput()}
        fields =['username', 'turns', 'units', 'rise', 'rescutL', 'rescutH', 'LorR']

#view
def importParameters(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ParaForm()
    else:
        form = ParaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            entry=dbPara(username = request.POST.get('username'),
                        turns = request.POST.get('turns'),
                        units = request.POST.get('units'),
                        rise = request.POST.get('rise'),
                        rescutL = request.POST.get('rescutL'),
                        rescutH = request.POST.get('rescutH'),
                        LorR = request.POST.get('LorR')
                        )
            entry.save()

    return render(request, 'main.html',
              {'ParaHTML' : form })

#url
urlpatterns = patterns('Inputs.views',
    url(r'^importParameters/$', 'importParameters', name='urlParameters'),
)

#main.html
<div class='col-lg-3'>
<h4>Set Rosetta Parameters</h4>
<action="{% url "urlParameters" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ ParaHTML|crispy }}
<input type="hidden" name = "username" value = "{{ user.get_username }}">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Set">
</form>
</div>
```

Appreciate any advice (better simple than 'most correct but complicated')
Could it be due to using default in the model?  Would that not 'fill in the form' and result in 'POST' at the initial visit to the page, resulting in just the button?  Thoughts?

Comment: One clue: I cannot ever see default values when the form finally loads: using Mushahid's advise  below, or adding initial={....} to: if request.method == 'GET':    form = ParaForm( initial =......)

Comment: What URL are you going to originally, to see the empty form?

Comment: Hi Daniel, should point to the view importParameters.  I would expect the form to be empty ( 'GET')  at first visit to the page, but as said, it just a button, no form fields

Answer (score 1):

One Suggesestion here ....

if Using **request.POST.get('anything')** simply then it Will raise error if particular string not find as in example('anything') string...

Because  **request.POST.get('anything')** will return **None** if 'anything' is not in request.POST.

Additionally, **.get** allows you to provide an additional parameter of a default value which is returned if the key is not in the dictionary.

e.g: Corrected  will be **request.POST.get('anything', 'mydefaultvalue')**

Comment: Thanks, Mushahid.  Tried it but it did not help. Good way to include defaults, will use it once my form is working.

Comment: Yeah Sure.. thats will be the good practice to start from scracth....                      I